# Trouble with calculating IN and OUT times for checking work sessions

Tags: python

```
Data:{user1:

{

`datetime.date(2023, 2, 1): [{'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 8, 1, 28)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 10, 38, 4)}, {'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 14, 54, 42)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 16, 20, 22)}, {'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 17, 15, 41)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 20, 20, 26)}], 

datetime.date(2023, 2, 2): [{'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 9, 39, 16)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 15, 4, 40)}],

datetime.date(2023, 2, 3): [{'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 8, 51, 23)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 14, 57, 16)}, {'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 15, 41, 36)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 15, 47, 40)}, {'event_time_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 16, 37, 28)}, {'event_time_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 17, 41, 50)}]`

}
}
```

So the above is the sample of the data I have. I have 25 similar records for each user and it's further nested as a dictionary with each day as the key and values are list of dictionary IN and OUT time.
The calculation lies within IN and OUT times.

"Calculate who had the longest work session in February and write it to a CSV file containing (user_id, session_length)

user_id - id of the user

session_length - a work session is a time between coming to the office and leaving to go home (an office exit with no re-entry for two hours counts as going home, thus marking the end of a work session). Breaks shorter than two hours count as part of the session.

e.g. IN 8, OUT 12, IN 13, OUT 18, (IN next day)

→ this counts as one session from 8 to 18

eg. IN 8, OUT 12, IN 15, OUT 18, (IN next day)

→ these count as two sessions from 8 to 12 and from 15 to 18"

So once the work session lengths are found, the max of session length will be considered for each day and max of session length for february will be considered for each user.

I tried working out the core logic, but I have been getting wrong answers.
I have written a pseudo code and stuck with the core logic for session calculation.

Pseudo code:

```
event_in = [t1,t2,t3,t4]
event_out = [t1,t2,t3,t4]


if event_in t2 - event_out t1 > 2hrs:
             then work_session  = event_out t1 - event_in t1
             this will be work session 1
elif:
       check for event_in t3 - event_out t2
       if the above is > 2hrs:
              then work_session = event_out t2 - event_in t1
              this will be work session 1 now
       else:
               check for event_in t4 - event_out t3
               if the above is > 2hrs:
                       then work_session = event_out t3 - event_in t1
                       this will now be work session 1
else:
        work session = event_out t4 - event_in t1
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach or if anybody could help me with it, it would be great. I know this can be achieved easily with Pandas, but I am trying to solidify python concepts and I believe sticking to the standard libraries will help me get better with logic.

```
def calculate_work_sessions(data):
    all_work_sessions = []

    for day, events in data.items():
        work_sessions = []
        current_session_start = None

        for event in events:
            if 'event_time_out' in event:
                if current_session_start:
                    session_end = event['event_time_out']

                    # Check if the time between the last in and this out is less than 2 hours
                    if session_end - current_session_start < timedelta(hours=2):
                        # Merge this out-in pair with the previous session
                        current_session_start = current_session_start
                    else:
                        # Start a new session
                        session_duration = session_end - current_session_start
                        work_sessions.append(session_duration)
                        current_session_start = None
                else:
                    # If there's no current session, just update the session end time
                    current_session_start = event['event_time_out']
            elif 'event_time_in' in event:
                if not current_session_start:
                    current_session_start = event['event_time_in']

        # If the last session extends beyond the last out time
        if current_session_start:
            last_out_time = max(event['event_time_out'] for event in events if 'event_time_out' in event)
            session_duration = last_out_time - current_session_start
            work_sessions.append(session_duration)

        all_work_sessions.append((day, work_sessions))

    return all_work_sessions

work_sessions_per_day = calculate_work_sessions(data)

for day, sessions in work_sessions_per_day:
    print(f"Sessions for {day}:")
    for i, session in enumerate(sessions, start=1):
        print(f"  Work Session {i}: {session}")
```

Comment: [code formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: Since events in and out obviously alternate, you could simplify the data by only keeping a list of times (without the 'in'/'out' keys); now for the breaks: just take time pairs at indexes 2*i+1, 2*i+2 for i in range(number_of_sessions - 1), and "remove" (or rather don't add them to another 'filtered_times' list) if their difference is <= 2h .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your function; I first create time_list by getting rid of the dictionary keys, after which I consider each (prev_session_out, next_session_in) couple and discard it if it's under 2 hours:

```
def calculate_work_sessions(data):
    all_work_sessions = []

    for day, events in data.items():
        time_list = [event_time for event in events for event_type, event_time in event.items()]
        number_of_sessions = len(time_list) // 2
        last_in = time_list[0]
        session_lengths = []
        for i in range(number_of_sessions - 1):
            prev_session_out = time_list[2 * i + 1]
            next_session_in = time_list[2 * i + 2]
            if next_session_in - prev_session_out >= datetime.timedelta(hours = 2):
                session_lengths.append(prev_session_out - last_in)
                last_in = next_session_in
        session_lengths.append(time_list[-1] - last_in)

        all_work_sessions.append((day, session_lengths))

    return all_work_sessions
```

Applied to your sample data:

```
Sessions for 2023-02-01:
  Work Session 1: 2:36:36
  Work Session 2: 5:25:44
Sessions for 2023-02-02:
  Work Session 1: 5:25:24
Sessions for 2023-02-03:
  Work Session 1: 8:50:27
```

Comment: Thank You Swifty! This helped me a lot. This was the core logic required to find max work session for each user in the month of february. I wrote rest of the code to accomplish this task. I will post that as well, if you find any improvements that could be made, that will be helpful.
Once again are there any pointers or resource that you can point me to for getting good with logics for the loop. I can understand the code, but have only started writing them a couple of months back, so lacking a bit of practise. WOuld appreciate your inputs on this as well :)

Comment: I don't really know resources for learning coding logic; I improve by solving problems (here and on other sites like Project Euler). I think practice makes perfect :)

Comment: Agreed! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import datetime

# Step 1: Read the CSV data
csv_data = []
with open('grouped_data.csv', mode='r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_data.append(row)

# Step 2: Organize the data by user and date
user_data = {}
for row in csv_data:
    user_id = row['user_id']
    event_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['event_time'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {}

    if event_time.date() not in user_data[user_id]:
        user_data[user_id][event_time.date()] = []

    user_data[user_id][event_time.date()].append(event_time)

# Step 3: Calculate work sessions using the existing function
def calculate_work_sessions(data):
    all_work_sessions = []

    for day, events in data.items():
        sorted_events = sorted(events)  # Sort events in chronological order
        number_of_sessions = len(sorted_events) // 2
        last_in = sorted_events[0]
        session_lengths = []
        for i in range(number_of_sessions - 1):
            prev_session_out = sorted_events[2 * i + 1]
            next_session_in = sorted_events[2 * i + 2]
            if (next_session_in - prev_session_out) >= datetime.timedelta(hours=2):
                session_lengths.append(prev_session_out - last_in)
                last_in = next_session_in
        session_lengths.append(sorted_events[-1] - last_in)

        all_work_sessions.append((day, session_lengths))

    return all_work_sessions

# Step 4: Create a list of tuples with user ID, date, and work session durations
result = []
for user_id, date_data in user_data.items():
    work_sessions = calculate_work_sessions(date_data)
    for date, durations in work_sessions:
        result.append((user_id, date, durations))

max_work_sessions = {}

for user_id, date_data in user_data.items():
    work_sessions = calculate_work_sessions(date_data)
    for date, durations in work_sessions:
        max_duration = max(durations, default=datetime.timedelta(0))  # Get the maximum duration for the day
        max_work_sessions[(user_id, date)] = max_duration

max_work_sessions_february = {}

# Define the target month (February)
target_month = 2  # February is the 2nd month

for (user_id, date), max_duration in max_work_sessions.items():
    if date.month == target_month:
        # Check if this user already has a recorded max duration in February
        if user_id not in max_work_sessions_february or max_duration > max_work_sessions_february[user_id]:
            max_work_sessions_february[user_id] = max_duration

# Define the CSV file name
csv_filename = "output2.csv"

# Write the results to the CSV file
with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    
    # Write the header row
    csv_writer.writerow(["user_id", "max_work_session_duration_in_February"])
    
    # Write the data rows
    for user_id, max_duration in max_work_sessions_february.items():
        formatted_duration = str(max_duration)
        csv_writer.writerow([user_id, formatted_duration])

print(f"Results have been written to '{csv_filename}'.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).